# How do I make a turn based game for two players who play with different devices on iOS?

Tags: networking, ios, game-center

I only have experience in physics-based games in cocos2d.

I want to develop a turn-based game in Cocoa Touch (iOS). Two players will play this game on different devices which connect via Bluetooth or Game Center.

I'd like to know how to synchronise two devices through a Bluetooth connection.

Please tell me of any blog tutorial, guide, or sample code which will help.

Comment: This question comes across very much as, "Please search the web for me".

Comment: i had searched more. But not get well.. So, that's why i post this question.. if you got anything related to my question than please tell me.... Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I done.. 
I have use this [blog tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22)

And do some logic with turn base.. Only maintain in this game center needs Send and Receive.. Thanks all who be a part of that..
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have network architecture questions, I refer to this wonderful document about how the Unreal Engine does it:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/NetworkingOverview.html

It's likely more than you need, but it's a great read and you'll likely be able to use concepts from it.

Comment: Thanks John. Your doc link very useful to networking concepts and it has lots of information.. But its not enough for my question.. If you have any other resource than tell me..

Answer (score 1):

How you synchronize the games is going to be very different from game to game.

You just need to figure out what both clients are going to need to send across, package that up, and send it.  There are some turn-based game helpers in iOS 5 that you can use to send messages back and forth.

Comment: hey Tetrad.. i am using ios 4.3 so, how to implement this type of game in. My requirement only how to sync one app in two different devices..